# Ninject Generating a TypeLoadException in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I am trying to execute the following test method using Ninject and MVC:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateEntityTest()
    {
        using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel())
        {
            kernel.Bind<IAccountControllerHelper>().To<AccountControllerHelper>();

            var a = kernel.Get<IAccountControllerHelper>();
            var p = a.GetPerson("jude-test-user-20130120");
            Assert.AreEqual(3, p.FriendlyId);
        }
    }
```

and it yields the following error:

> Test method
>   YellowLlama.Web.Tests.AccountControllerHelperTests.CreateEntityTest
>   threw exception: System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules
>   violated by type: 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.Filter.FilterContextParameter'.
>   Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base
>   type or be less accessible. at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes() at
>   Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForAssembly.HasNinjectModules(Assembly
>   assembly) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Language\ExtensionsForAssembly.cs:
>   line 25 at Ninject.Modules.CompiledModuleLoaderPlugin.b__0(Assembly
>   asm) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Modules\CompiledModuleLoaderPlugin.cs:
>   line 81 at
>   Ninject.Modules.AssemblyNameRetriever.AssemblyChecker.GetAssemblyNames(IEnumerable1
>   filenames, Predicate1 filter) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Modules\AssemblyNameRetriever.cs:
>   line 114 at
>   Ninject.Modules.AssemblyNameRetriever.AssemblyChecker.GetAssemblyNames(IEnumerable1
>   filenames, Predicate1 filter) at
>   Ninject.Modules.AssemblyNameRetriever.GetAssemblyNames(IEnumerable1
>   filenames, Predicate1 filter) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Modules\AssemblyNameRetriever.cs:
>   line 54 at
>   Ninject.Modules.CompiledModuleLoaderPlugin.LoadModules(IEnumerable1
>   filenames) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Modules\CompiledModuleLoaderPlugin.cs:
>   line 81 at Ninject.Modules.ModuleLoader.LoadModules(IEnumerable1
>   patterns) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Modules\ModuleLoader.cs: line
>   60 at Ninject.KernelBase.Load(IEnumerable`1 filePatterns) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs: line 236 at
>   Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(IComponentContainer components,
>   INinjectSettings settings, INinjectModule[] modules) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs: line 89 at
>   Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs: line 57 at
>   Ninject.StandardKernel..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\StandardKernel.cs: line 46 at
>   YellowLlama.Web.Tests.AccountControllerHelperTests.CreateEntityTest()
>   in AccountControllerHelperTests.cs: line 18

I have scoured the web and tried the few suggestions that I have found to no avail.